# Required facebook integration for adding page tab on seller page

Tags: facebook

I(Merchant) have a eCommerce store where buyers can buy a sellers product.

Now i want to implement tab on seller's Facebook page. Where i can list all their products.

Is this possible by coding? ASp.net or javascript.

Comment: Your question is interesting but too broad.